# how to get Jenkins to be assessable from aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

so this is the problem I have installed open jdk 8 for jenkins. jenkins is insalled and running given

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-10-21 19:22:55 UTC; 20min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 437 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 21 19:22:52 ip-172-31-30-187 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Oct 21 19:22:53 ip-172-31-30-187 jenkins[437]: Correct java version found
Oct 21 19:22:53 ip-172-31-30-187 jenkins[437]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Oct 21 19:22:54 ip-172-31-30-187 su[619]: (to jenkins) root on none
Oct 21 19:22:54 ip-172-31-30-187 su[619]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (u>
Oct 21 19:22:54 ip-172-31-30-187 su[619]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Oct 21 19:22:55 ip-172-31-30-187 jenkins[437]:    ...done.
Oct 21 19:22:55 ip-172-31-30-187 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

however, using  `serverip:8080` brings up nothing

used this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6K1IF-489M&t=36s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6K1IF-489M&t=36)

port 8080 is also added to security group

Comment: Check your NACL whether incoming and outgoing traffic has been allowed properly. Check if your subnet where EC2 lives has been connected to internet gateway. Make sure you are not behind vpn, some vpn disallows connection at port 8080. Make sure your EC2 is accessible when running normal web server at port 80. Make sure you use http and not https if you dont install any ssl cert in your ec2.

Comment: hm, I have HTTPS and HTTP in the security group however, I haven't tried to change the port that jenkins uses to 80 so ill try that. Also when I use a default react app server it works fine with it in the security group.

Comment: this did not fix this issue changed --https or http port and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was not solved but making a fresh ec2 instance and installing Jenkins by following that tutorial did the trick

Comment: It's a comment not an answer you may comment it with Add a comment